# Why is there no `_heappush_max()` in python?

Tags: python-3.x, heap

I am looking through the official python [repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/heapq.py) and I am noticing there is no max variant for `heappush`,but they have the other max implementations for `pop` and `_siftup`.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are intended for internal use only (see also [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) on leading underscore): they serve here for the implementation of the public [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) and [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) functions, which may need a max-heap to produce the result, but never need to *push* an element on that max-heap.

As these functions do not belong to the public interface, you should not rely on them. In future versions, they may be removed, be renamed, or behave differently.

We can wonder why Python does not include an interface for supporting maxheaps. Some considerations:

- This is just a decision of the designers, and this might change in the future
- The equivalent of a max heap with numbers, is a min heap with these numbers negated.
- There are packages that support maxheaps just like `heapq` supports minheaps, like for instance this [heapq_max](https://pypi.org/project/heapq_max/).

Comment: Understood, that makes sense. I guess what I am really asking is why doesn't python have max heap functions (i.e. something like `heapify_max()`, `heappush_max()` etc) when they have all most of the relevant internal functions already implemented?

Comment: See addition to answer.